# Making a convertto-html table fragment searchable and sortable

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I have been beating my head on the wall with this one for a while now. I am using PowerShell to gather various pieces of information from multiple computers at once and display them in a simple HTML report. The deployment method can only use the script and no other files. I can export single html files and make them sortable using the instructions in this [article](https://davidtruxall.com/interactive-powershell-convertto-html/). Which is fine and dandy, but I need to have multiple tables organized on a page. Thus I need to use fragments. I have tried to tweak the java scripts for fragments buy it just doesn't want to go. The other method I tried works better, but it's one line at a time kind of deal and the searching doesn't seem to function as well as I would hope. I found it on  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_desc). This allows a single table to be sortable if I make some replacements to the code.

```
$Processes = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process | Select-Object Caption, ProcessID, @{L = "VM(mb)"; e = { "$([math]::Round($_.Vm/1mb,2))" } }, @{l = "WS(mb)"; e = { "$([math]::Round($_.WS/1mb,2))" } } | Sort-Object "WS(mb)" | ConvertTo-Html -as table -Fragment
```

Then going line by line for the TH replacing each object just for searchability on that single table.

```
$processes = $Processes -replace '<table>','<table id="sortable">'
$processes = $Processes -replace '<th>Caption','<th onclick="sortTable(0)">Caption'
$processes = $Processes -replace '<th>VM\(mb\)</th>','<th onclick="sortTable(0)">VM(mb)</th>'
```

For searching, I have tried a jquery with no success as well. The article can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp). I believe this is due to the fact that the thead is not added by default Powershell. Here is the code that's a work in progress. It's pretty ugly, forgive me.

```
write-host "I am going to gather information about this machine. Thank you."

#-------------Bios----------------
$BiosInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS | Select-Object Status, Name, Manufacturer, SerialNumber, Version, ReleaseDate | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment
#------------OS-------------------
$OSInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Status, FreePhysicalMemory, Caption, InstallDate, LastBootUpTime, LocalDateTime, Numberofusers, version, buildnumber, EncryptionLevel, OSarchitecture, RegisteredUser, SerailNumber, SystemDrive, SystemDirectory, SystemDevice, WindowsDirectory | ConvertTo-Html -as List -Fragment
#------------Chassis--------------
$chassis = Get-CimInstance -Class win32_systemenclosure | Select-Object -ExpandProperty chassistypes
$theChassis = switch ($chassis) {
    3 { "Desktop" }
    4 { "Low Profile Desktop" }
    5 { "Pizza Box" }
    6 { "Mini Tower" }
    7 { "Tower" }
    8 { "Portable" }
    9 { "Laptop" }
    10 { "Notebook" }
    11 { "Hand Held" }
    12 { "Docking Station" }
    13 { "All In One" }
    14 { "Sub Notebook" }
    15 { "Space-Saving" }
    16 { "Lunch Box" }
    17 { "Main System Chassis" }
    18 { "Expansion Chassis" }
    19 { "Sub Chassis" }
    20 { "Bus Expansion Chassis" }
    21 { "Peripheral Chassis" }
    22 { "Storage Chassis" }
    23 { "Rack Mount Chassis" }
    24 { "Sealed-case PC" }
    Default { "Unknown" }
}
#--------------RamChips-------------
$MemoryChips = Get-CimInstance -Class win32_physicalmemory | Select-Object * | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ChipNumber   = $_.banklabel 
        Size         = [math]::Round($_.capacity / 1gb)
        Speed        = $_.configuredclockspeed
        Manufacturer = $_.manufacturer 
        PartNumber   = $_.partnumber 
        SerialNumber = $_.serialnumber
    } # End Return Add  
} | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment 
$MemoryBanks = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray | Select-Object MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices
#-------------Hard Disks------------
$PhysicalDisks = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Diskdrive | Select-Object Status, DeviceID, @{L = "Size"; e = { "$([math]::Round($_.size/1gb))/1gb" } }, Caption, MediaType, Manufacturer, Model, SerialNumber | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment 
#-------------Hot Fixes ------------
$HotFixes = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_QuickFixEngineering | Select-Object Description, HotFixID, InstalledBy, InstalledOn | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment 
Write-Host "Grabbing Programs"
$Softwares = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_product | Select-Object Name, Version, Vendor | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
$Processor = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_processor | Select-Object Name, DeviceID, datawidth, maxclockspeed, socketdesignation, l3cachesize, numberofcores, numberoflogicalprocessors, threatcount, processorid | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment 
$Bitlocker = Get-BitLockerVolume | Select-Object MountPoint, EncryptionMethod, VolumeStatus, EncryptionPercentage, @{l = "Key"; e = { $A = ""; $_.Keyprotector | foreach-object { $A = "$A$_," }; $A } } | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment 
$Monitors = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object DeviceID, MonitorType, Screenheight, screenwidth, description | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment
$NetworkConfig = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_networkadapterconfiguration | Where-Object { $null -ne $_.macaddress } | Select-Object @{l = "DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder"; e = { $j = ""; $_.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder | foreach-object { $j = "$j$_," }; $j } }, @{l = "Description"; e = { $i = ""; $_.Description | foreach-object { $i = "$i$_," }; $i } }, @{l = "DHCPEnabled"; e = { $h = ""; $_.DHCPEnabled | foreach-object { $h = "$h$_," }; $h } }, @{l = "DHCPServer"; e = { $g = ""; $_.DHCPServer | foreach-object { $g = "$g$_," }; $g } }, @{l = "IPAddress"; e = { $f = ""; $_.IPAddress | foreach-object { $f = "$f$_," }; $f } }, @{l = "DNSServerSearchOrder"; e = { $e = ""; $_.DNSServerSearchOrder | foreach-object { $e = "$e$_," }; $e } }, @{l = "DefaultIPGateway"; e = { $d = ""; $_.DefaultIPGateway | foreach-object { $d = "$d$_," }; $d } }, @{l = "IPSubnet"; e = { $c = ""; $_.IPSubnet | foreach-object { $c = "$c$_," }; $c } }, @{l = "MACAddress"; e = { $b = ""; $_.MACAddress | foreach-object { $b = "$b$_," }; $b } } | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment
$NetNeighbor = Get-NetNeighbor | Where-Object { ($_.LinkLayerAddress -notlike "00-00-00-00-00-00") -and ($_.LinkLayerAddress -notlike "FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF") -and ($null -notlike $_.LinkLayerAddress) } | Select-Object IPAddress, @{L = "MacAddress"; e = { $_.LinkLayerAddress } }, State, PolicyStore | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
$LogicalDisks = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_logicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, @{L = "FreeSpace"; e = { "$([math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace/1gb),2))gb" } }, @{L = "Space"; e = { "$([math]::Round(($_.Size/1gb),2))gb" } } | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Fragment
$Startups = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_StartupCommand | Select-Object name, location, Command, User | ConvertTo-Html -as table -Fragment
$Processes = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process | Select-Object Caption, ProcessID, @{L = "VM(mb)"; e = { "$([math]::Round($_.Vm/1mb,2))" } }, @{l = "WS(mb)"; e = { "$([math]::Round($_.WS/1mb,2))" } } | Sort-Object "WS(mb)" | ConvertTo-Html -as table -Fragment
$Services = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service | sort-object Name | Select-Object ProcessID, name, StartMode, State, Status, ExitCode | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
$UserProfiles = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Select-Object Localpath, Special, Loaded, LastUseTime | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
$NetworkAdapter = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapter | Select-Object DeviceID, name, AdapterType, ServiceName | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment
$HTML = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.sortableyall.tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 15%;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
th {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#252525;
    color:#fafafa;
}
/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size:17px;
}
table {
    width:100%;
}
table td, table td * {
    vertical-align: top;
}
/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.collapsible {
    background-color: #707070;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  .active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #505050;
  }
  
  .content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 85%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 100%;
  font-size 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>$($ENV:COMPUTERNAME)</h2>
<p>A $theChassis</p>
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'OSOverView')">OS Info</button>
<button class="collapsible">Operating System</button>
<div class="content">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'BiosInfo')">Bios Info</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'OSInfo')">OS Info</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'HotFixes')">Hot Fixes</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'LogicalDisks')">Logical Disks</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'UserProfiles')">User Profiles</button>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Hardware</button>
<div class="content">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Processor')">Processor</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'MemoryChips')">Memory Chips</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'PhysicalDisks')">Physical Disks</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'NetworkAdapter')">Network Adapters</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Monitors')">Monitors</button>
    
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Software</button>
<div class="content">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Softwares')">Installed Software</button>    
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Bitlocker')">Bit Locker</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Startups')">Start up programs</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Processes')">Processes</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Services')">Services</button>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Network</button>
<div class="content">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'NetworkConfig')">Network Configurations</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'NetNeighbor')">Net Neighbor</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="OSOverView" class="tabcontent">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%;vertical-align:Top;"><h3>Logical Disks</h3>$LogicalDisks</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%;vertical-align:Top;"><h3>Bios Info</h3>$BiosInfo</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>OS Info</h3>
            $OSInfo
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan=2>
            <h3>User Profiles</h3>
            $UserProfiles
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
            <h3>HotFixes</h3>
            $HotFixes
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="BiosInfo" class="tabcontent">$BiosInfo</div>
<div id="OSInfo" class="tabcontent">$OSInfo</div>
<div id="HotFixes" class="tabcontent">$HotFixes</div>
<div id="LogicalDisks" class="tabcontent">$LogicalDisks</div>
<div id="UserProfiles" class="tabcontent">$UserProfiles</div>
<div id="Processor" class="tabcontent">$Processor</div>
<div id="MemoryChips" class="tabcontent"><b>$($MemoryBanks.MemoryDevices)</b> with a $($MemoryBanks.MaxCapacity) Compacity<br>$MemoryChips</div>
<div id="PhysicalDisks" class="tabcontent">$PhysicalDisks</div>
<div id="NetworkAdapter" class="tabcontent">$NetworkAdapter</div>
<div id="Monitors" class="tabcontent">$Monitors</div>
<div id="Softwares" class="tabcontent">$Softwares</div>
<div id="Bitlocker" class="tabcontent">$Bitlocker</div>
<div id="Startups" class="tabcontent">$Startups</div>
<div id="Processes" class="tabcontent">$Processes</div>
<div id="Services" class="tabcontent">$Services</div>
<div id="NetworkConfig" class="tabcontent">$NetworkConfig</div>
<div id="NetNeighbor" class="tabcontent">$NetNeighbor</div>
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  
    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
  
    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
</script>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

"@
$HTML > $env:HOMEDRIVE\report.html 
Invoke-Expression $env:HOMEDRIVE\report.html
```

Thank you for any direction you can give.

Comment: You should really check out this module. https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML

Comment: if I could install this on the end-users computer, I would. However, I can not.